# Format footers at L/R margins AND retain sequential page numbering between rotated pages

Tags: microsoft-word

Over the years I have found ways to get Word to do most of what I wanted, such as indented formatting that actually cooperates.

My hope was to discover how to keep page numbering in a footer progressing on multiple pages, *and* formatted to fit left and right margins, when going from portrait to landscape then back to portrait again.

One can have all footers be the same width, say, 6 1/2 inches on portrait pages with 1" margins, but that looks odd on a landscape sheet. If I want them  to be wider on the landscape page, I apparently have no option to keep the numbering continuing *and* stretch the left and right margin text/numbering to fit 1" margins (9" apart) on the occasional landscape page in a multi-page, mostly-portrait-oriented document.

I can have wider footers on landscape sheets, or continued footer numbering on the whole document, but not both? Can someone please tell me how that is accomplished?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you would like to define a universal footer for the whole document that mixes portrait-oriented and landscape pages. Isn't a "Insert alignment tab" in "Header and Footer Tools" (Word 2010) what you are looking for? In a footer on the first page you put a text that should be aligned left, then insert alignment tab with right alignment and then insert page number field. In this way footer on next pages (portrait-oriented or landscape) will stretch from left to right margin.

Comment: That isn't enough. I want to create a document that has 1. Both landscape and portrait pages, 2. Header and footer formatting that is 6” wide on the portrait pages, 9” wide on the landscape pages, and 3. To have the headers and footers on all pages update when I make a text change to page one's header or footer (a revision letter change, for example). I may be asking too much, but I just want this level of linking for a document control scenario when revising a document, to be able to edit only page one, and not have to go through the whole doc's headers and footers to see they all updated.

Comment: This is exactly what you can get if you use alignment tab. You can have both kinds of pages, different widths of headers and footers (stretching from margin to margin) and headers and footers updated when change is made in one place ("Link to Previous" should be selected in every section in "Header and Footer Tools").